# how to set background image no-repeat for outlook 2007 and above version

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email, vml

I want to add background image to email template for outlook but in outlook image show repeatedly. I tried below code, but it didn't work.

Also I tried with

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
        <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
          <v:fill type="frame" src="https://valasysb2bmarketing.com//email-raw/email-9.png" color="#f6f6f6"/>
        </v:rect>
<![endif]-->
```

this code,but this also not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Background Image Issues in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71204408/background-image-issues-in-outlook)

Comment: No, this is not the answer. I want to set background image with no-repeat for Outlook

Answer (score 1):

For non-tiled background images that work in Outlook, as well as other email clients, use something similar to:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#f6f6f6" background="https://valasysb2bmarketing.com//email-raw/email-9.png" width="600" height="987" valign="top" style="background-image: url('https://valasysb2bmarketing.com//email-raw/email-9.png');background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center;background-size:contain;background-color:#f6f6f6;width:100%;height:auto;padding:0;">
        <!--[if mso]>
        <v:image xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style=" border: 0;display: inline-block; width: 450pt; height: 740pt;" src="https://valasysb2bmarketing.com//email-raw/email-9.png" />                
        <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="border: 0;display: inline-block;position: absolute; width: 450pt; height:740pt;">
        <v:fill  opacity="0%" color="#f6f6f6"  />
        <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if !mso]>--><div><!--<![endif]-->
            <!-- OVERLAYED CONTENT START -->
            <table width="600">
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding:10px 90px 200px 90px">
                        <p>Overlay content asdf asdf  asdf asdf  asdf asdf  asdf asdf  asdf asdf  asdf asdf  asdf asdf  asdf asdf  asdf asdf  asdf asdf  asdf asdf  asdf asdf  asdf asdf  asdf asdf  asdf asdf  asdf asdf  asdf asdf  asdf asdf  asdf asdf  asdf asdf </p>
                        <p>Overlay content</p>
                        <p>Overlay content</p>
                        <p>Overlay content</p>

                        <p>Overlay content</p>
                        <p>Overlay content</p>
                        <p>Overlay content</p>
                        <p>Overlay content</p>
                        <p>Overlay content</p>
                        <p>Overlay content</p>
                        <p>Overlay content</p>
                        <p>Overlay content</p>
                        <p>Overlay content</p>
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- OVERLAYED CONTENT END -->
        <!--[if !mso]>--></div><!--<![endif]-->
        <!--[if mso]></v:textbox></v:fill></v:rect></v:image><![endif]-->
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Note the width and height for Outlook are the width and height for the image multiplied by 0.75 (i.e. 600px x 0.75 = 450pt).

This doesn't come without it's issues though.

First, you need a certain amount of content to view the background image.

Second, this probably doesn't work for mobiles.

Third, any variation of text may make it look bad.

I suggest you do in fact use a tiled background, with 1px border on a table for the black border, and a new table row with the orange email as a separate (foreground) `<img>`. That way, your content can easily grow without layout issues.